# Trying out TingoDB: Issue passing global var to insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, tingodb

I am testing and benchmarking a couple of embedded dbs using node.js. With TingoDB, anybody knows why this works

```
var test = { hello:'world' };
for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    collection.insert(test, { w: 1 }, function () {})
}
```

but this not:

```
for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    var test = { hello:'world' };
    collection.insert(test, { w: 1 }, function () {})
}
```

That is, in the first case the database gets filled up with records till `size`, while in the second case only 1 entry is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between both code examples provided by you.

Also, `test` is a global variable in both cases. `for` doesn't create it's scope, and due to hoisting your second code examples look like this:

```
var test;
for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    test = { hello: 'world' };
    collection.insert(test, { w: 1 }, function () {});
}
```

As you can see, it's almost like the first one. The only difference is that it creates a new `{ hello: 'world' }` object and assigns it to `test` variable each time. So `collection.insert` will get same data in both of your code examples.

I believe the problem is somewhere in the code you didn't provide here.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's more that I'm fairly new to writing async code. Other than the code bit I provided, there's not much else. I was just adapting literally from here https://github.com/sergeyksv/tingodb#usage , I guess I'll have to take it up as a bug with the developer... I will accept your answer, because now I have at least confirmation it's not hoisting nor scope.